# How to fetch and display "unpivot" SQL in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

[image: My table which is "unpivot"]

I built a table which had to contain 42 columns which would be a large one, I decided to use rows as columns and used a column to add values of the respective fields. I've used dtsid as common entity.

Assuming that there are different values for every dtsid.
If in a page, I set $dtsid = $_GET['dtsid'] and run this url "exam.ple/result.php?dtsid=%Any_dtsid%"

How do I fetch the data and display values in different parts of html using php?

Comment: 1. You get all rows and display them. If you need a specific entity, query for that. 2. I hope you are not very far in your project, and you can "pivot it back". 42 columns are no problem, and even if they would be, a better solution would be to split them in e.g. 2 tables, maybe one with name/password/age, one with the address. Look at some sample table in the internet and do what they do; your design is a solution for specific problems and is not useful to learn how relational databases work. 3. Having an entity twice for a dtsid (here: timestamp) will kill everything you are trying to do.

Comment: Your entities are attributes. Just sayin'.